# Having the error "Trying to redefine primary-key column" in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In `model.py`:

```
class Robot(Base):
    __tablename__ = "robot"

    id = Column('id', Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    qq = Column('id', Integer, default=0)
    count = Column('id', Integer, default=0)
```

In another file, I used it and  it throws the exception:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Trying to redefine primary-key column 'id' as a non-primary-key column on table 'robot'
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are naming all your columns as `'id'`:

```
id = Column('id', ...
qq = Column('id', ...
count = Column('id', ...
```

**Fix:**

```
id = Column('id', Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
qq = Column('qq', Integer, default=0)
count = Column('count', Integer, default=0)
```